# How to set minHeight of <div> in dependency of another div in Angular/PrimeNG

Tags: html, angular, primeng

In my Angular Project I do have two containers:

- One LineChart
- One Information Card showing some Sensor Data from Database.
  Both are in one line, 2 columns when Browser is in Full screen.
  For Styling we use the PrimeNG Paradise Theme.
  The requirement is, that the InformationCard on the right side does always have the same height as the LineChart Component on the left.
  I did implement some service (height.service.ts) which I wanted to use for getting the height value from left to right:

```
export class HeightService {
   private height = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');

    setHeight(height: string){
        this.height.next(height)
    }

    getHeight() {
        return this.height.asObservable();
    }
  constructor() { }
}
```

The LineChartComponent looks like this:

```
export class LineChartComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, AfterViewInit, AfterContentInit, OnDestroy{

    dataAvailable: boolean = false;

    @ViewChild('lineChartElement') lineChartElement;
    private containerHeightUpdateInterval: number;

    constructor(private heightService: HeightService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.setContainerHeight();
        }, 1000)
    }

    @HostListener('window:resize', [])
    onResize() {
        this.setContainerHeight()
    }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.setContainerHeight()
    }

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        this.setContainerHeight()
    }
    setContainerHeight() {
        let height = `${this.lineChartElement.nativeElement.offsetHeight}`;
        this.heightService.setHeight(height);
    }
}
```

```
<div class="card"  #lineChartElement>
    <div class="card-header">
        <h4>{{title}}</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div *ngIf="dataAvailable">
            <p-chart type="line" [data]="showData" [options]="lineOptions" [style]="{'width': '50%'}"></p-chart>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The InfocardComponent looks something like this:

```
export class EnergyViewComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, AfterViewInit{
    dataAvailable = false;

    //containerHeight -> inherit from LineChart
    containerHeight: string;

    constructor(private heightService: HeightService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.heightService.getHeight().subscribe((height) => {
            this.containerHeight = height;
        })

        setInterval(() => {
            this.getContainerHeight();
        }, 1000)
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.heightService.getHeight().subscribe((height) => {
            this.containerHeight = height;
        })
    }

    getContainerHeight() {
        //TODO: Fix alignment when page is in fullscreen
        //TODO: set new Containerheight when orientaiton of mobile device is changing
        this.heightService.getHeight().subscribe((height) => {
            this.containerHeight = height;
        })
    }
}
```

```
<div *ngIf="sensorType == 'Shelly3EMPro'">
        <div class="card summary" [style.min-height.px]="containerHeight"> <!-- TODO: Find some solution to get containers with same height -->
       <!--<div class="card summary"> -->
        <div class="card-header">
            <h5>{{title}}</h5>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="dataAvailable" class="grid p-nogutter">

            <div class="col-6 md:col-3"> <!-- There are exactly 6 of this elements, all styled the same -->
                <div class="summary-item blue" [style.opacity]="selectedDateIsToday ? 1 : 0.2">
                    <h5>Aktuelle Leistung</h5>
                    <h3>10 kW</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Both componets getting called like this:

```
    <div *ngIf="dataAvailable">
        <div *ngFor="let item of sensorIds">
            <div class="grid p-fluid " style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap;" >
                <app-line-chart class="col-6" style="flex-wrap: wrap;" ></app-line-chart>
                <app-energy-view class="col-6" style="flex-wrap: wrap;"></app-energy-view>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The Effect I'm getting is, that when the Browser is in Full Screen, the minHeight seems to be completely ignored.

As soon as I open the Chrome Dev Tools an changing the dimensions of the browser window, the right component gets updated with the correct height. When going back in Full Screen Mode the minHeight gets ignored again.

I already tried updating the minHeight Attribute every second with an Interfal, I tried so Delay before setting the hight, tried differen LifecycleHooks (e. g. OnViewInit(), OnChange(), set the Service as Observable, etc...)
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be achieved without angular and by using PrimeFlex

https://www.primefaces.org/primeflex/height

you already have a row wrapper. you just need to add the `h-full` class to your app-energy-view component

```
 <div *ngIf="dataAvailable">
    <div *ngFor="let item of sensorIds">
        <div class="grid p-fluid " style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap;" >
            <app-line-chart class="col-6" style="flex-wrap: wrap;" ></app-line-chart>
            <app-energy-view class="col-6 h-full" style="flex-wrap: wrap;"></app-energy-view>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`h-full` should extend the height to fully fill the parent div.

Comment: Nice, that brings me at least a bit closer to my goal. The behaviour now is, when loading the Project in Full Screen, it does work as I want.  As soon as I go in Window mode, the hight is not getting updated. Only when i change the window dimensions, it gets corrected. When going from here to full screen, again, the div-height is not getting updated. Only a reload of the whole page does the trick.